# matplotlib: most efficient way to update a set of wedge patches

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a GUI that allows a user to create sets of points using shapes (e.g. a circle with center at X, Y and diameter D, with N points where X, Y, D, & N are inputs using entry boxes).

From the generated set of points, I plot the points as well as calculate the 2D centroid and plot that. To plot the centroid I'm using 4 wedges to plot a 4-quadrant black and white circle.

The data plots fine (I initialize a scatter plot with a blank data set and then add data to it each time the user generates an input). To plot the centroid though I'm a bit of a loss. I can calculate and plot a centroid from a given set of data, but I'm not sure of the most "efficient" way to do the updating.

Should I initialize a "blank" centroid symbol and then update the center of the wedges somehow (not sure how to do this given my centroid function) similar to the method used for the full dataset, or should I just delete and re-create the centroid each time more data is generated (and how would I do that)?

Leaving out the code for generating all the data points and just plotting a centroid gives:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import numpy as np

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.patches import Wedge, Circle
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")


class MainGUI(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title('Title')
        self.geometry('750x500')

        self.nb = ttk.Notebook(self)
        self.nb.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=5, rowspan=4, sticky='NESW')
        self.tab2 = ttk.Frame(self.nb)
        self.nb.add(self.tab2, text='Tab2')

        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        tab2_r = 8
        tab2_c = 4
        for i in range(tab2_r):
            self.tab2.rowconfigure(i, weight=1)
        for i in range(tab2_c):
            self.tab2.columnconfigure(i, weight=1)

        self.makeWidgets()
        self.initializePlot()

    def makeWidgets(self):
        self.Labels = []
        self.Entries = []
        self.labText = [('X Location:'), ('Y Location:')]

        self.xGrid = 1
        self.yGrid = int(np.ceil(len(self.labText) / self.xGrid))
        i = 0
        for j in range(0, self.xGrid + 1, 2):
            for k in range(self.yGrid):
                if(i == len(self.labText)):
                    break
                else:
                    self.label = tk.Label(self.tab2, text=self.labText[i])
                    self.label.grid(column=j, row=k + 8, sticky='SW')
                    self.Labels.append(self.label)
                    self.entry = tk.Entry(self.tab2)
                    self.entry.insert(0, '0.0000')
                    self.entry.grid(column=j + 1, row=k + 8, sticky='NS')
                    self.Entries.append(self.entry)
                    i += 1

        self.addBtn = tk.Button(self.tab2, text='Add Entry', command=self.plotstuff)
        self.addBtn.grid(column=self.xGrid + 1, row=self.yGrid + 9, sticky='NSEW')

    def initializePlot(self):
        self.fig = Figure(figsize=(1, 1), dpi=100)
        self.ptrnFig = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.ptrnFig.axis('equal')
        self.ptrnFig.axis([-5, 5, -5, 5])
        self.ptrnFig.spines['left'].set_position('zero')
        self.ptrnFig.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
        self.ptrnFig.grid(True)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, self.tab2)
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=4, rowspan=5, sticky='NSEW')
        self.scat = self.ptrnFig.scatter([], [], c="b", marker="o")     # Used to plot full dataset

    def plotstuff(self):
        # self.scat.set_offsets(dataset) <---- Used to plot full dataset, updated each time data entered
        self.points = np.array([float(self.Entries[0].get()), float(self.Entries[1].get())], ndmin=2)
        self.cog = self.plotCOG((self.points[0, 0], self.points[0, 1]), 0.1, angle=0, ax=self.ptrnFig)
        self.canvas.draw_idle()

    def plotCOG(self, center, radius, angle=0, ax=None, colors=('w', 'k'), **kwargs):
        if ax is None:
            ax = plt.gca()

        # Some code here to delete old COG?

        theta1, theta2, theta3, theta4 = angle, angle + 90, angle + 180, angle + 270
        w1 = Wedge(center, radius, theta1, theta2, fc=colors[0], ec='k', **kwargs)
        w2 = Wedge(center, radius, theta2, theta3, fc=colors[1], ec='k', **kwargs)
        w3 = Wedge(center, radius, theta3, theta4, fc=colors[0], ec='k', **kwargs)
        w4 = Wedge(center, radius, theta4, theta1, fc=colors[1], ec='k', **kwargs)
        for wedge in [w1, w2, w3, w4]:
            ax.add_artist(wedge)


def main():
    MainGUI().mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I have tried multiple forms of ax.remove() such as

```
for wedge in [w1, w2, w3, w4]:
    wedge.remove()
```

at the beginning of the plotCOG function (after attempting to check if the wedges are already plotted), but can't seem to find anything that works.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach seems to be correct. The only problem is that you have no reference to the old wedges. So you can store them somewhere to be able to use them later on.

```
def initializePlot(self):
    # ....
    self.wedges = []


def plotCOG(self, center, radius, angle=0, ax=None, colors=('w', 'k'), **kwargs):
    ax = ax  or plt.gca()

    for wedge in self.wedges:
        wedge.remove()

    # ..
    w1 = Wedge(..)
    w2 = Wedge(..)
    w3 = Wedge(..)
    w4 = Wedge(..)

    self.wedges = [w1, w2, w3, w4]
    for wedge in self.wedges:
        ax.add_artist(wedge)
```

Comment: Thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnes. It took me a minute to realize even after I implemented your comments that I was calling my plotCOG function as self.wedges = plotCOG(...) so I was getting another error. Your solution works perfectly. Cheers.